# VBA connection via ODBC (3.0.6) / ADODB to MariaDB 10.3.8

Tags: excel, vba, odbc, mariadb

I downloaded and installed the MariaDB ODBC Driver 3.0.6 and installed it on my computer. Then I wrote a small piece of VBA in EXCEL 2016 which connects to the DB, which seems to work, and tries to query some entries.

Here is where the problems start:

- The recordset allways returns a RecordCount of -1
- EXCEL crashes when executing any rs cursor command (MoveLast etc.), but that is probably because I don't have any recors
- If I use CursorLocation adUseClient, as suggested in many posts I could find, instead of asUseServer VBA throws the following error: **Runtime error '-2147467259 (80004005)' ... returned Status E_FAIL**

**Edit:**
The issue was officialy fixed in the following versions:  3.0.7, 2.0.19, 3.1.0
[Link to Issue](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/ODBC-192)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution: use MariaDB ODBC Driver **3.0.5** instead of 3.0.6. Then everything works fine with the adUseClient Cursor...

Perhaps it saves someone a little time... :-)

Comment: Officialy fixed in the following Versions: 3.0.7, 2.0.19, 3.1.0    

See here: [MariaDB Jira](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/ODBC-192)